# Any way to configure action titles and respective deeplinks in clevertap for iOS notifications?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, rich-notifications, clevertap

iOS 11 supports rich notifications with custom configured action items for notifications which are configured in the app. Is there any possibility of configuring the action items and its deeplinks in the thirdparty notifcation platforms like clevertap?

The action buttons that could be visible dynamically for every notification in notification panel of iphone for a push notification sending from clevertap or any other notification platform. Apps like message/mail/whatsapp have action items like reply or forward, i need such action buttons that should configure dynamically for every notification we send and that action would have a deeplink to forward to system. Is this ever done?

Answer (score 1):

This link - https://github.com/CleverTap/CTNotificationContent#configure-your-notification-content-extension-to-use-the-ctnotificationviewcontroller-class should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://clevertap.com/blog/ios-rich-notifications-are-here/) was the 3rd result when I googled "clevertap iOS notifications". Is this what you're asking about?

Comment: No, it was not. I was asking about the action buttons that could be visible dynamically for every notification in notification panel of iphone for a push notification sending from clevertap or any other notification platform. Apps like message/mail/whatsapp have action items like reply or forward, i need such action buttons that should configure dynamically for every notification we send and that action would have a deeplink to forward to system. Is this ever done?